ld.exe: cannot find ./fsa/mobid/libfsa.a: No such file or directory
I'm trying to run mingw32-make from cmd (msys2) and I get the following error for a
Nordic Semiconductor:
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, realpath --relative-to=. nRF5_SDK, ...) failed.
Makefile:98: pipe: No error
Linking target: _build_mobid/nrf52832_xxaa.out
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./fsa/mobid/libfsa.a: No such file or directory
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): warning: _close is not implemented and will always fail
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0xe): warning: _fstat is not implemented and will always fail
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): warning: _isatty is not implemented and will always fail
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x10): warning: _lseek is not implemented and will always fail
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x10): warning: _read is not implemented and will always fail
C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/13.2 Rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): warning: _write is not implemented and will always fail
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [nRF5_SDK/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common:294: _build_mobid/nrf52832_xxaa.out] Error 1

The path to the ARM Toolchain is added in the makefile.windows, which is called from makefile.common. I couldn't find any info on what libfsa.a is.
Any ideas?
I tried to downgrade the version from 13.2 Rel1 to 10 2021.10. Error persists.
Tried with different mingw environments, but it doesn't help, same result.
Makefile.common:294:
%.out:
    $(info $(call PROGRESS,Linking target: $@))
    $(NO_ECHO)$(GENERATE_LD_INPUT_FILE)
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LD_INPUT) -Wl,-Map=$(@:.out=.map) -o $@
    $(NO_ECHO)$(SIZE) $@


Does that file exist?

libfsa.a doesn't exist, nor can I find what it is.

Then check with whoever gave you that makefile and project.  It's probably a dependency you'll need to build or find elsewhere.
